# How to increase the devices stack size in Android?

Tags: android, stack-overflow

Morning, I'm using Android Studio 2.2 and a Galaxy TAB A 2016. 
I have a method that calculates the FFT of a digital signal. There are a lot of recursive calls and the Memory runs out really quick. Android Studio says:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
              Process: com.example.lou.test, PID: 13533
              java.lang.StackOverflowError: stack size 8MB
```

don't I have more than 8MB of stack? Is there a way to increase the stack size of the device? 
I've searched for similar problems, but I can only find how to increase the Android Studio's RAM size.

Comment: does that happens to every app you run or this prticular single app ?

Comment: Can you consider uploading the information to the server and let the server do the computation then returns back to your device?

Comment: This is my first app, so I don't have experience with other apps. Same error wen I'm using another android device. I would like to know if this is the complete stack size of my device or if it is possible to allocate more resources. Uploading to a server is not possible, so I decided to cut off the FFT buffer from ~8k to ~4K.

Comment: @LuisGarcia show us yoyr line of code where crash begin